# handle backbutton with MobileService.LoginAsync()

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, back-button, azure-mobile-services

I have a mobileService on azure I want to connect to and it works fine with this command:

```
MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);
```

The problem for me is if a user presses the backbutton on the mobile, then it will exit, and I will show a messagebox where the user can opt for quitting or try signing in again.

But when a user want to try and sign in again, I receive an error message that the login procedure is already in progress. How can I circumvent this? Is there a way to kill the procedure? 
I have tried with overriding the back button but this did not work.
Has anyone solved this problem?

**EXTRA**

I have now also tried with:

```
using Microsoft.Live;
```

Here a connection is also easy to create and a lot nicer with information. As I here can keep the user signed in after closing of the app.

But still if the users says no the software will not allow me to start a new login process.
Have anybody solved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the session you create to logout instead of the login procedure. everything works then.